Button stuck in hovered state on touch in WPF Touch Application modal window
I'm developing a WPF application designed for touch screens. There is a modal window with button "New" on it. The button has 3 states:

Normal:



Hovered (orange background):



Pressed (orange background, small font size):


When I tap the button time to time, it changes to the Hovered state (orange background) and doesn't execute the command. To return it to the Normal state, I have to tap it multiple times, and only then it successfully executes the command.
Although when I use mouse this never happens.
This issue does not occur when using a mouse, leading me to initially suspect it might be a touch screen lag. However, I've reproduced the issue on different devices.
Button xaml code:
<controls:IconButton
    Text="{loc:Localization NEW}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Style="{StaticResource SecondaryButton}"
    Command="{Binding SelectAndCloseDialogCommand}"/>

The IconButton class inherits from Button and adds a few Dependency Properties that are used in the styles but does not contain any additional logic.
Button Styles:
<Style x:Key="SecondaryButton"
       TargetType="{x:Type controls:IconButton}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MainFontColor_AppColorBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource SecondaryAppColorBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="60" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="150" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24" />
    <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2 0 2 2" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
    <Setter Property="Effect">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" Direction="320" ShadowDepth="3" BlurRadius="5" Opacity="0.5" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:IconButton}">
                <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}">
                            <Grid Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Left">

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                     Visibility="{TemplateBinding IconVisibility}"
                                     Margin="2 10">

                                    <Path Stretch="Uniform"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                      Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                      Data="{TemplateBinding PathData}"
                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding MarginIcon}"/>
                                </Viewbox>

                                <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                                            Visibility="{TemplateBinding TextVisibility}"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            Margin="10 2"
                                            Grid.Column="1"/>

                            </Grid>
                        </Viewbox>
                        <Polygon Fill="{DynamicResource MainFontColor_AppColorBrush}"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                 Opacity=".4" Margin="4"
                                 Points="15,15 0,15 15,0"
                                 Visibility="{TemplateBinding BottomArrowVisibility}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledPrimaryButtonColor}" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

Has anyone experienced a similar issue with buttons in WPF touch applications? What might be causing this problem, and how can I resolve it?
I also thought the button was somehow stuck in the Hovered state, so I tried changing the ClickMode value to Press, but that didn't work.
UPD: My main goal is to ensure that the button responds and executes the command on the first touch.

Hovered state is useless for touch. So you can try to stop entering Hovered state when touch. Or you can capture TouchLeave event and cancel Hovered state.

@emoacht Thank you, the IsMouseOver trigger isn’t necessary. I attempted to remove both the IsMouseOver and IsPressed triggers from the styles, but unfortunately, the button still doesn’t respond on the first touch.

I cannot reproduce your issue on command.
